# odoo many2one as selection field in combobox

Tags: python, odoo

I'm creating a module in odoo and I wanna use a many2one as a selection field, the problem is on the name of the city 'ville en francais' the dropdown works and it saves the id of the city(from database) but the name is like obj.ville,1 (it shows the name of the module, id instead of the name of the city in database)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlzv0.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVaP4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXOPl.png)

Answer (score 0):

put below in your model which is related with Many2one

`_rec_name = 'field_you_want_to_show_in_dropdown'`

Comment: like that ou non ???
from odoo import models, fields, api

class villeMO(models.Model):
 _name = 'ville.mo'
 

 ville = fields.Char(string="ville",required=True)
 
class paya(models.Model):
 _name='paya.mo'

 numb = fields.Many2one('ville.mo',_name='ville',ondelete="cascade",string="city")

Comment: hello khalid i edited my answer you can add  _rec_name = 'ville' into 'ville.mo' model not like fields.Many2one('ville.mo',_name='ville',ondelete="cascade",string="city")

Comment: hank you very much for your help